# Remove inner border and extend dangles to outer border

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, topology

I'm struggling with a massive file of grids that need borders extend or snapped onto the outer border of the file. I'm looking to batch this process as I'm currently using topology and and tracing borders then redrawing them and then cutting after doing the entire file.

I have tried many things and am now out of ideas and have come to you for help.

I have Arcgis Advanced users licence and don't wish to buy new product or addons.
[Starting Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0lpO.jpg)
[image: Final Extended Grid]